# Are two partitions with HFS+ and exFAT more efficient or just one with exFAT for storing data?

Tags: linux, windows, macos, hard-drive, partitioning

I use Mac, Windows, and Linux(Ubuntu) computers, and one 1 TB external hard drive. I mainly use Mac, and don't want to use third party drivers. Is it more efficient to:

1. Use one partition for `HFS`(Mac OS Extended) and one for `exFAT`(**two partitions in total)**, or
2. Only use **one** `exFAT` partition

Additionally, if Option 1, what are the advantages of `HFS` on Mac and Linux systems?

Answer (score 0):

OS X can only boot from HFS+, so I like to keep an HFS+ partition on my external disk, with a clean install of OS X on it, in case I need to boot from something else while repairing my internal disk.

Comment: I probably should have made it more clear, but I wanted this in regard to storing data. However, do you mean I should store data on the exFAT partition and store a clean install of OS X on the HFS+ partition?